# Broken DAG: urllib3 1.25.3 (/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages), Requirement.parse('urllib3<1.25,>=1.21'), {'sagemaker'}

Tags: python, airflow, amazon-sagemaker, urllib3

I have created a DAG in Airflow with SageMakerOperators and I have not been able to make them work. The title is the error that appears in the airflow GUI. For solving it, I have made the following tries:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall urllib3 && sudo pip3 install urllib3==1.22 
sudo pip3 install urllib3==1.22 --upgrade
sudo pip3 install urllib3==1.22 -t /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages -upgrade
```

But I am still getting the error in the GUI. Plus, in the console of the webserver I am getting:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3-1.22.dist-info/METADATA'
```

The thing is that if I make `pip3 show urllib3` I get the version 1.22:
[image]

However, it says dist-packages instead of site-packages. In addition, trying to go to `/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3-1.22.dist-info/` for trying to solve the metadata file not found error, the directory does not exists. 
[image]
[image]

I am totally lost at this point. How could I solve this problem?

Comment: You installed `urllib3` for all users but `airflow` is looking in the local library for the package. It's weird but try doing `pip3 install --user urllib3==1.22`. It may fix the issue.

Comment: Making that and rebooting the machine worked

Comment: @absolutelydevastated would you like to post your comment as answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

Airflow is looking in the local (user) Python installation for the library but `urllib3` is installed for all users. It's weird but try doing `pip3 install --user urllib3==1.22`.